# Why can't I tail a log in powershell when I run it from the run Window?

Tags: powershell, tail

If I open a Power Shell window and run the following command it works fine...

```
get-content -Path C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\90\tmpDF49.tmp -wait
```

But if I open the run menu (WINKEY+R) and then run it like this:

```
powershell -command 'get-content -Path C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\90\tmpDF49.tmp -wait'
```

it opens a powershell window and then just closes...

I've also tried the same thing from a powershell script and it just closes up...just like with the run menu:

```
[Diagnostics.Process]::Start("powershell.exe", "-command `"get-content -Path $($tmpFile) -wait`"")
```

Shouldn't it keep waiting and trying to tail the log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the following from the run line:

```
powershell -NoExit -command "Get-Content -Path C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\90\tmpDF49.tmp -wait"
```

The `-command` switch is designed to run the provided command and exit unless `-NoExit` is specified. `-NoExit` must come before the `-command` parameter by design as well.

Running `PowerShell.exe -Help` will divulge this information. I have been told that not all of the information is accurate, but the statements above appear to be.